Websites refuses URL with brackets
We're working on a wordpress website and we have a plugin named Ajax filters.
When I select a filter, it's loading, and in my network tab, I can see the first query : ?filters=product_cat[2199]
But a few seconds later, another query is made to ?filters=product_cat2199
and my filters doesn't work, nothing else is happening, the products aren't filtered.
I've got no errors.
Does anyone have any idea what could be causing the problem?
My first thought was .htaccess, but it doesn't seem to have any problems.
Here's my .htaccess file :
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
 
# Ne pas bloquer les URL avec des crochets
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

see the screenshot of redirections

What actual response did the first request get? Is it an explicit Location header pointing to the new (faulty) URL? And what is the response status code?

First one with bracket is 302 Found, the second one without brackets is 200 OK, but doesn't work

Okay, if you rename the .htaccess for a second, to disable everything it does, and then you call the first URL again, directly - is it still getting redirected?

If I remove / rename my .htaccess, I just keep getting a 404 error until I put it back

Okay, because geogrilles is a WP page to begin with, I suppose, that makes sense. Are you just using the "default" .htaccess for WP, or do you have more in there? If it isn't the "standard", then please show us. Next step would be to see if the behavior persists, when you disable all WP plugins temporarily.

I added my .htaccess file to the first post. I don't know if it's the one by default because it's a customer's website. I did not modified it tho.

The WP part looks pretty standard. But the server appears to be using mod_security, so maybe that is to blame? (https://www.netnea.com/cms/apache-tutorial-8_handling-false-positives-modsecurity-core-rule-set/ appears to talk about similar issues, but in relation to Drupal.) You should probably ask the responsible server admin about the issue.

It's weird because it used to work until now. Will try to disable wp plugins to check if it works.
Other ideas are welcome
